# Is $\zeta(s)\sim\sqrt{\frac{\zeta(4s)}{\zeta(2s)}}\prod\limits_{n=1}^\infty\big(1-\frac{2}{p_n^s+p_n^{-s}}\big)^{-1/2}$?

Tags: proof-verification, prime-numbers, proof-explanation, riemann-zeta, conjectures

The Riemann Zeta function, denoted by $\zeta(\cdot)$, is defined by the following equation for $s > 1$ and $p_n$ the $n^\text{th}$ prime number. $$\zeta(s)=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\bigg(1-\frac{1}{p_n^s}\bigg).$$

I came across a [recent conjectural proof](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.09519.pdf) online that

> $$\zeta(s)\sim\sqrt{\frac{\zeta(4s)}{\zeta(2s)}}\prod_{n=1}^\infty\bigg(1-\frac{2}{p_n^s+p_n^{-s}}\bigg)^{-1/2}$$

with RHS $\gtrsim$ LHS and a formula for the radical consisting of... *Bernoulli numbers???* I don't know.

I thought I might share this to see what your thoughts are on the online paper. If this conjecture is true, what exactly would it tell us about the relationship between prime numbers and the Riemann hypothesis: much or little?

Here area few examples of $s\in\{2,3,4,5\}$ for which the greater the value of $s$, the more accurate the equation. $$\begin{align} \zeta(2)&\simeq\frac{\pi^2}{\sqrt{105}}\prod_{n=1}^\infty\bigg(1-\frac{2}{p_n^2+p_n^{-2}}\bigg)^{-1/2}\ (0.00127009\%\text{ error})\\ \zeta(3)&\simeq \pi^3\sqrt{\frac{691}{675675}}\prod_{n=1}^\infty\bigg(1-\frac{2}{p_n^3+p_n^{-3}}\bigg)^{-1/2}\ (\text{nearly exact henceforth})\\ \zeta(4)&\simeq \pi^4\sqrt{\frac{3617}{34459425}}\prod_{n=1}^\infty\bigg(1-\frac{2}{p_n^4+p_n^{-4}}\bigg)^{-1/2} \\ \zeta(5)&\simeq \pi^5\sqrt{\frac{174611}{16368226875}}\prod_{n=1}^\infty\bigg(1-\frac{2}{p_n^5+p_n^{-5}}\bigg)^{-1/2}\end{align}$$

What does anyone have to say about this? Is this going to revolutionize the way we perceive the Riemann Zeta function; i.e. is this *exciting news* for the math community? Can this be entirely confirmed or not? `:)`

I have no idea, really. Me loving math and all just knows that $\zeta(\cdot)$ is a very important function.

Comment: But why is the zeta function important? (apart from the Riemann hypothesis).

Comment: @Zacky because of the first equation. I mean, the *other* formula for $\zeta(s)$ is $$\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^s}$$ but that alone does not concern prime numbers.

Comment: @Zacky oh, apart from the Riemann hypothesis, idk.

Comment: How did you calculate the error? Is it due to a partial product or have or actually evaluated it to a very high numerical limit?

Comment: @Klangen the author has provided the value of RHS $\zeta(s)$ and its LHS. I simply did $1-\text{RHS}\div \text{LHS}$ to find how close the LHS is equal to the RHS and then I multiplied it by $100$ to find the percentage. To get accurate calculations, I used wolfram alpha.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*I am sorry, I don’t understand the sense of your question. Because, it's trivial:*

Using  $~\displaystyle\zeta(s)=\prod\limits_p\frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}~$ we get $~\displaystyle\frac{\zeta(s)^2\zeta(2s)}{\zeta(4s)}=\prod\limits_p\frac{1}{1-\frac{2}{p^s+p^{-s}}}~$

by using $~\displaystyle \frac{1}{1-\frac{2}{x+x^{-1}}}=\frac{x+x^{-1}}{x+x^{-1}-2}=\frac{(\frac{1}{1-x^{-1}})^2\frac{1}{1-x^{-2}}}{\frac{1}{1-x^{-4}}}~$ .

*There's nothing special to say about the primes here.*

The question is reducible on a discussion of $~\displaystyle\frac{\zeta(2s)}{\zeta(4s)}=\prod\limits_p (1+p^{-2s})~$ .

$\displaystyle n\in\mathbb{N} : ~~\zeta(2n)=(-1)^{n-1}\frac{(2\pi)^{2n}}{2(2n)!}B_{2n}~$ where $~B_k~$ are the [*Bernoulli numbers*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliNumber.html) .

Comment: This looks right to me...not sure why 68 people have overlooked it. The first line seems to make the point.

Comment: @Daniel: I think the OP is trying to understand if the formula is something special. And indeed: It is *not*. That's the answer. ;) Nice that you see it that way too.

Comment: Oh... well, arguing with the truth would be arguing with reality, so I suppose the paper doesn't really mean anything, then :\

Comment: @user477343 : The author is talking about a "simple formula for the magnitude of the Riemann zeta function" . I haven't checked if his calculations are o.k., maybe it is so. But the formula which you have mentioned is indeed nothing special. And the author uses this as a tool, not only as a result.

Comment: Ok, then. I will accept this answer. I am unfamiliar about Bernoulli numbers, so perhaps this question of mine was a bit too advanced, but I was heavily curious about it. Now that you have demonstrated how the formula is (unfortunately) nothing special, I will give you the tick. Nice answer!

Comment: @user477343 : Thank you! ;)

Comment: No problemo! :P

Comment: @Klangen : Thanks for the bounty!